# Subversion failed on Centos

Tags: apache, svn, centos

My apache server failed once I rebooted my centos server. When I try to start the service I get this error:

httpd: Syntax error on line 35 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_dav_svn.so: undefined symbol: dav_register_provider

Reading some articles I found that I need to load mod_dav.so before mod_dav_svn.so but I don't have this file in my server.

Reinstalling subversion don't worked too.

Any idea ??? thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you don't have mod_dav.so?  Do you have the line

```
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
```

in your httpd.conf?  Perhaps you can post the relevant parts of your conf file.

In regards to why you're seeing it once you rebooted, perhaps you made some changes and hadn't yet restarted the apache service, meaning that it's just not showing you the problems.

Comment: hi there :) I didn't have this line LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so I added it once I get the error. But now I have other error. mod_dav.so not found. I tried to find this file but I don't have it in my system.

Comment: To be clear, take a look at this page: [link](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion). You can install it simply using "yum install mod_dav_svn subversion". If you do have that file and just not mod_dav, I believe you need to recompile Apache with "--enable-dav-module". Running "httpd -M" will show what modules it's loading.